# Implicit type conversion occurs in df.where

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to replace np.nan with None using `df.where`.

However, a type conversion occurs in the non-replace column.

Why does this problem occur?

Example:

```python
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 1.0, 'b': 1.1, 'c': True, 'd': np.nan,}])
print(df)
#      a    b     c   d
# 0  1.0  1.1  True NaN

df_new = df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None)
print(df_new)
#    a    b     c     d
# 0  1  1.1  True  None

print(df.dtypes)
# df.dtypes
# a    float64
# b    float64
# c       bool
# d    float64
# dtype: object

print(df_new.dtypes)
# df_new.dtypes
# a     int64 <- The type of column a has been converted from float64 to int64!
# b    object
# c      bool
# d    object
# dtype: object
```

Environment:

```bash
$ python -V
Python 3.7.5
$ pip freeze | grep -e pandas -e numpy
numpy==1.21.6
pandas==1.2.5
```

Note that I have confirmed that implicit type conversion does not occur if the version of pandas is 1.3.0 or higher.

Comment: Why are you using `np.where()` instead of `df.fillna()`? Does the problem happen if you use `fillna()`?

Comment: If this doesn't happen in higher versions, it seems like it's a bug that they fixed.